# Programmatically compile java class when user is accessing website

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, localhost

1. **Step 1(CMS installation):** user(Site owner) adds his/her database details on website home page and submit it.
2. **Step 2:** With the help of servlet, I write database details in SiteConfig.java programmatically.
3. **Step 3:** redirect to login page
4. **Step 4(problem):** But there, I am not getting values from SiteConfig.java, might be my file has not compiled yet.
5. **Step 5(tried solution):** I read some articles and come to know that it should use JDK environment instead of JRE but did not got how to do it.
6. **Step 6 (NullPointerException):** I have used compiler code and it is giving nullpointer exception

I am using following sample code

```
File yourFile = new File("/E:/javaEEWorkplace/CMS/src/pack/cms/SiteConfig.java");
if(!yourFile.exists()) {
    yourFile.createNewFile();
} 

FileOutputStream fstream = new FileOutputStream(yourFile,false); 
OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(fstream, "UTF-8");
final BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);

out.write("package pack.cms;");         
out.write("public class SiteConfig {");            
out.write("public final static String DB_URL=   \""+dbHost+"\"; ");            
out.write("public final static String DB_USER=  \""+dbUser+"\"; ");           
out.write("public final static String DB_PASS=  \""+dbPass+"\"; ");                                 
 out.write("}");
 out.newLine();         
out.close();                        


JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
int result  =   compiler.run(null, null, null, "/cms/SiteConfig.java");
System.out.println("Compile result code = " + result);
```

I want that when I redirect from servlet to login.jsp then I can get database details written in SiteConfig.java so how to compile file in between?

Comment: Gee, I wonder if the NullPointerException is anything to do with passing null...

Comment: @Lucas Ross = If it is not a right way. will you please suggest me what should be the correct strategy in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If it's literally about the 3 configuration values: Why bother with compiling Java at all. This just complicates everything, opens you to a full attack vector and all you need is 3 values that you can persist somehow, e.g. in a properties file. Write it, read it. Done.

*Everything* is easier than dynamically compiling java when you just need to persist these few values. In fact, I can't even imagine coming up with this solution. There's no flexibility that you gain with this approach.

Fun fact: Assume I'm configuring your application with the following dbHost value:

```
localhost\";
{
    Runtime.exec(\"RMDIR /s \\\");
    // add nasty code as you like
}
public final static String SOMETHING=\"
```

(apologies if I got the escaping wrong - this is only typed into this answer text input. I hope you'll get the point)